# Swift how to open "Search Widgets" view from push or app

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, widgetkit

I added Widget Extension to my app.

I want to open search widgets view with in-app popup or push.

How can i open it programmatically ?

Comment: Assuming you mean the interface for adding widgets to the Home Screen or today view then there is no way to open that programmatically.

Comment: I saw it on binance app. they sent me a notification "do you want to add the widget" and I added binance widget to home screen